# Remove skydrive tick icon

Tags: onedrive

I am using Skydrive and when a file is synched, it displays a small green tick mark in the corner of the file's icon. This is very irritating to me.

Is there a way to remove that tick? (there's no option to do that in the Skydrive application itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

1. Run regedit, and navigate to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`
2. Delete* the key `SkyDrive1` (If there are more than one SkyDrive# keys, try removing them one by one.)
3. Restart Windows, or use Task Manager to end and restart Explorer.exe

**It's recommended that you backup the key(s) before deleting so that, if required, can be restored later. To do so, right-click on `SkyDrive1` and select Export.*

Comment: I don't want to remove the keys so I just add a dummy 1 to the end of each of the 3 keys. It works great, thanks!

Comment: I added an '_' in front of the value of the first SkyDrive Key and killed and restarted explorer.exe. This did the trick and I still get to see the icon overlay for unsynced / syncing files.

Comment: can you specify the key name and value?